# variables inside struct set to 0

Tags: ios, swift, class, struct

I wrote a struct inside a class. This struct gets initialized once in the `renderView()` method.  Every time I call the `timer.pause()` function, the variable `currentTime` is set to 0. I can't figure out why, the variable inside the struct is not being affected by that method at all.  The struct itself is not being newly initialized, either.

Why would it change `currentTime` ?

Here is my code:

```
//Class 
override func renderView() -> UIView {
    let view = super.renderView("TimeWidget")
    timer = Timer()
    return view
}


func currentOrientation(orientation: UIDeviceOrientation) {
    if orientation != .Portrait{
        timer.start({ (newTime) in
            self.timeLabel.text = (self.date + newTime.seconds).toString(DateFormat.Custom("HH:mm:ss"))
        })
    }else{
        timer.pause()
    }
}

//Helper
extension TimeWidget{
    struct Timer {

        private var _timer: NSTimer!
        private var currentTime: Int!

        init(){
            currentTime = 0
            _timer = NSTimer()
        }

        mutating func start(onTimeChange: (newTime: Int)->Void){
            _timer = NSTimer.every(1.0) {
                self.currentTime = self.currentTime + 1
                onTimeChange(newTime: self.currentTime)
            }
        }

        func pause(){
            _timer.invalidate()
        }

        mutating func reset(){
            _timer.invalidate()
            currentTime = 0
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

`renderView()` is called from a UICollectionViewCell:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
        //render View
        cell.addSubview(widgets[indexPath.row].renderView())

        //define height
        cell.frame = cell.standardFrameWithHeight(widgets[indexPath.row].height)

        return cell
}
```

Comment: check if you are really not going into init() again

Comment: When do you call renderView()?

Comment: Why not deleting the `init()` function and set the default values in the declaration lines? An implicit unwrapped optional for a counter which will never be `nil` is meaningless anyway.

Comment: @Lu_ i am sure, made a breakpoint at the `init()` function.
@ff10 i edited my initial post
@vadian strangely enough, if i remove the `init()` function, timer keeps being nil after i call `timer = Timer()`